# How to write this using pointer arithmetic instead of indexes

Tags: c++, pointers

`x3[i][j] += x1[i][k]*x2[k][j];`

Using indexes this works but I don't know how to write it using pointer arithmetic such as: `*(x+i)` instead of `x[i]`

Comment: `x3[i][j]` = `(x3[i])[j]` = `*((x3[i])+j)` = `*(*(x3+i)+j)`. Yes, the result is confusing.

Comment: Thanks it works now, you are right it is confusing.
For multiplying 2 it is just another bracket before pointer asterix as well.

Answer (score 0):

`*(*(x3+i)+j) += (*(*(x1+i)+k)) * (*(*(x2+k)+j));`